# Fill bar plot gaps in matplotlib with pandas resampled time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some code like the follwoing MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

test_df = data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2015-10-01')
test_df = test_df.resample('W', how='sum')['Volume']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(test_df.index, test_df, edgecolor='None')
```

Which results in a plot like this:

[image]

How can I make the bars span the axis so there are no gaps between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`width`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) keyword argument.  Since you're doing a weekly resample, setting `width=7` should do the job.

```
ax.bar(test_df.index, test_df, edgecolor='None', width=7)
```